# dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version ,Cannot find module 'nocache'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I really hope some of you can help me.
So I did some upgrates at one of my old app (which it is already on the store), and then when I tried to upload the apk it said I needed an API 30 (mine was 29). So I tried to upgrade the SDK and expo. Since that moment everything doesen't work.
Here sending the errors I have:

expo start ..

```
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:

 - expo-ads-admob - expected version: ~10.0.4 - actual version installed: 8.3.0
 - expo-font - expected version: ~9.1.0 - actual version installed: 8.3.0
 - expo-updates - expected version: ~0.5.4 - actual version installed: 0.3.5
 - react-native-gesture-handler - expected version: ~1.10.2 - actual version installed: 1.7.0
 - react-native-reanimated - expected version: ~2.1.0 - actual version installed: 1.13.4
 - react-native-safe-area-context - expected version: 3.2.0 - actual version installed: 3.1.4
 - react-native-screens - expected version: ~3.0.0 - actual version installed: 2.10.1
 - react-native-unimodules - expected version: ~0.13.3 - actual version installed: 0.12.0

Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.

To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo doctor --fix-dependencies,
or install individual packages by running expo install [package-name ...]
Cannot find module 'nocache'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\gameZone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-server-api\build\index.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\metro\importMetroFromProject.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\MetroDevServer.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\start\startDevServerAsync.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
Error: Cannot find module 'nocache'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\gameZone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-server-api\build\index.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\metro\importMetroFromProject.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\MetroDevServer.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\start\startDevServerAsync.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at _nocache (C:\Users\gameZone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-server-api\build\index.js:105:39)
    at createDevServerMiddleware (C:\Users\gameZone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-server-api\build\index.js:164:47)
    at createDevServerMiddleware (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\middleware\devServerMiddleware.ts:54:7)
    at runMetroDevServerAsync (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\MetroDevServer.ts:96:32)
    at startDevServerAsync (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\src\start\startDevServerAsync.ts:77:49)
    at startAsync (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\src\start\startAsync.ts:69:41)
```

and when I try  "expo doctor --fix-dependencies", this is what happens:

```
Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.
Installing 8 SDK 41.0.0 compatible native modules using npm.
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react-native-screens@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-screens
npm ERR!   react-native-screens@"~3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-screens@">= 2.0.0-alpha.0 || >= 2.0.0-beta.0 || >= 2.0.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/stack@"^5.9.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@react-navigation/drawer)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-screens@"^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha" from react-navigation-drawer@1.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-navigation-drawer
npm ERR!   react-navigation-drawer@"^1.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I also tried "npm install" and "yarn install" and to upgrade manually some of the depandencies of the list, for example "react-native-screen" or "react-font". But same errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to delete your package.lock.json  then rerun the command

```
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `npc expo install --check` now.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to solve this issue

1. Updating expo and running expo update to set the dependencies to something compatible with my SDK seemed to solve the issue for me
   npm install -g expo-cli
   expo update